# Saving pdf in MongoDb using GoLang mgo

Tags: jquery, mongodb, file, go, mgo

I read multiple blogs about saving the file using mgo, but unable to find a solution for below specific need, help shoutout!

Below inserts object in MongoDb:

```
var dbSchoolPojo dbSchool
i := bson.NewObjectId()
dbSchoolPojo.ID = i
coll := db.C("school")
coll.Insert(&dbSchoolPojo)
```

Below able to get hold of file:

```
file, handler, err := r.FormFile("pdf") //Able to get file from r *http.Request
```

Now, before inserting object, I need to set above file like:

```
dbSchoolPojo.pdf = file.Bytes(); //Of course Bytes() is invalid method
```

My structs object:

```
type dbSchool struct {
    ID  bson.ObjectId  `json:"id" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    ...
    Pdf  []byte  `json:"pdf" bson:"pdf"`
    ...
}
```

In layman's term, the question is: How do I insert file (received from HTML form) in mongoDb via GoLang struct using mgo driver?

Thanks for reading! :)

---

> Update:

PDF is stored in MongoDB like below:

```
Binary('EWHKDSH876KJHlkjdswsddsfsd3232432njnjkn2dljDSFSDFIJSFD333...')
```

Below code works without error, but doesn't serve PDF file:

```
func DownloadPdf(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, db mongoDB) {
    var school dbSchool
    coll := db.C("schools")

    incomingId = "59e6404e2f68182a74610f19"; //This mongo DB _id is received from GET URL request

    err := coll.Find(bson.M{"_id": bson.ObjectIdHex(incomingId)}).
        Select(bson.M{"pdf": 1}).One(&school)
    if err != nil {
        serve404(w, r, db)
        return
    }

    buffer := school.Pdf
    w.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=abc.pdf")
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/pdf")
    w.Header().Set("Content-Length", strconv.Itoa(len(buffer)))

    if _, err := w.Write(buffer); err != nil {
        log.Println("unable to serve image.") //This line is not executed
    }
}
```

JQuery code to request content:

```
      $(".downloadPdfFile").click(function() {
            var domain = document.location.origin;
            window.open(domain+'/brochure/59e6404e2f68182a74610f19', '_blank');
         });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `file` returned by [`Request.FormFile()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.FormFile) is of type [`multipart.File`](https://golang.org/pkg/mime/multipart/#File) which is:

```
type File interface {
    io.Reader
    io.ReaderAt
    io.Seeker
    io.Closer
}
```

It implements [`io.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader), so you can simply read its content e.g. with [`ioutil.ReadAll()`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadAll):

```
data, err := io.ReadAll(file)
// Handle error
```

Then:

```
dbSchoolPojo.Pdfdata = data
```

But storing big files as part of documents is not optimal / efficient. Instead take a look at the [MongoDB GridFS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/) that is also supported by `mgo`: [`Database.GridFS()`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Database.GridFS).

Here's how you can store a file in MongoDB GridFS (example taken from [`GridFS.Create()`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#GridFS.Create)):

```
func check(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.String())
    }
}
file, err := db.GridFS("fs").Create("myfile.txt")
check(err)
n, err := file.Write([]byte("Hello world!"))
check(err)
err = file.Close()
check(err)
fmt.Printf("%d bytes written\n", n)
```

Using `GridFS`, you can also save the file without having to read all its content into memory first, if you "stream" the file content into the [`mgo.GridFile`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#GridFile), as it implements [`io.Writer`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer). Call [`io.Copy()`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Copy):

```
// ...
file, handler, err := r.FormFile("pdfFile")

// ...
mongoFile, err := db.GridFS("fs").Create("somepdf.pdf")
check(err)

// Now stream from HTTP request into the mongo file:
written, err := io.Copy(mongoFile, file)
// Handle err

err = mongoFile.Close()
check(err)
```

**Edit: update answering your update**

When you serve the PDF, you query the document in a wrong way:

```
err := coll.Find(bson.M{"_id": bson.ObjectIdHex(incomingId)}).
    Select(bson.M{"pdf": 1}).One(&school)
```

You select the `pdf` field to retrieve, but your documents in MongoDB have no such field:

```
type dbSchool struct {
    ID  bson.ObjectId  `json:"id" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    ...
    Pdfdata  []byte  `json:"pdf"`
    ...
}
```

This type definition will result having a `pdfdata` field, but not `pdf`. Add the proper `mgo` struct tag:

```
type dbSchool struct {
    ID  bson.ObjectId  `json:"id" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    ...
    Pdfdata  []byte  `json:"pdf" bson:"pdf"`
    ...
}
```

Or change the selected field from `pdf` to `pdfdata`.

Comment: Hello @icza, it worked! One more question: Now I get byte data in struct object, next step is to convert this data in to pdf file and allow user to download it via web browser. Can you help with that?

Comment: @NikhilJoshi For start check out this question: [PDF download is not working from serverside in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41238407/pdf-download-is-not-working-from-serverside-in-golang).

Comment: Hello @icza, I tried but it doesn't work completely. Please see UPDATE in the original post.

Comment: There was typo, it is Pdfdata only, please see edited update portion. Am I missing anything?

Comment: @NikhilJoshi Please read my answer carefully. MongoDB will use a field named `"pdfdata"`, with **lowercase letter**, yet you project with `"Pdfdata"` with uppercase.

Comment: Typo again, a debug shows that I am getting pdf data in bytes.

Comment: @NikhilJoshi Now you project the `"pdf"` field again. I wrote in my answer that without `bson` tag value on `dbSchool.Pdfdata`, the default field nam will be `"pdfdata"`. The `json` tag value is unrelated to `mgo`. Please, please read my answer.

Comment: I edited my earlier update, used "Pdf" instead of "Pdfdata" everywhere. I also read that AJAX can't convert bytes to PDF file, hence I just tried opening a new window. Everything is working as expected now!! Thanks a ton!